# Testing API Controller that returns ActionResult<T>

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq

Testing the following controller

```
public class AnnouncementController : Controller
{

    IConfiguration _configuration;

    IHostingEnvironment _env;

    ILoggerManager _logger;

    public AnnouncementController(IConfiguration configuration, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerManager logger)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
        _env = env;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet ("{employeeID}/{moduleID}")]
    public ActionResult<Announcements> GetAnnouncements([FromRoute]int employeeID, [FromRoute] int moduleID)
    {
       try
       { 
          Services.Interface.IAnnouncementService service = new Services.Imp.AnnouncementService(_configuration, _logger);///establishing new Service connection

           if (service != null)
           {
               Announcements announcements = service.GetAnnouncements(employeeID, moduleID);       

               return announcements;
           }
           else
           {
               return BadRequest("Unable to establish connection.");
          }
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          _logger.LogError(ex.Message, ex);//log error
        return BadRequest(ex.Message);
      }
    }
}
```

With the following testing code:

```
public void ForSessionActionResult_ReturnsObjectResult()
{
    IConfiguration _configuration;
    IHostingEnvironment _env;
    ILoggerManager _logger;

    var mock_logger = new Mock<ILoggerManager>();
    _logger = mock_logger.Object;
    var mock_configuration = new Mock<IConfiguration>();
    _configuration = mock_configuration.Object;
    var mock_env = new Mock<IHostingEnvironment>();
    _env = mock_env.Object;

    var sut = new AnnouncementController(_configuration, _env, _logger);
    int employeeID = 1;
    int moduleID = 1;
    var result = sut.GetAnnouncements(employeeID, moduleID);

    var actionResult = Assert.IsType<ActionResult<Announcements>>(result);
    Assert.IsType<NotFoundObjectResult>(actionResult.Result);

}
```

I'm getting `BadRequestObjectResult` on `Assert.IsType NotFoundObjectResult` on the controller being tested.

I am not sure if I am mocking correctly the controller constructor to begin with.

But on the last Assert I'm getting `BadRequestObjectResult`.

Comment: Just to say - your `IAnnouncementService` should be a dependency and should be injected through constructor for sure. Perhaps, this service should be actually tested, but not controller.

Comment: Also, you shouldn't really be returning Bad Request on all exceptions. Imagine yourself on the position of a consumer of your API. Bad request means "a caller made something wrong", but exception means "there is an unexpected error in the code".

Comment: InternalServerError (500) is more appropriate in this case.

Comment: Nowhere in the code under test do you return a `NotFoundObjectResult` yet you try to assert that the SUT could potentially return something it does not use.  Second the SUT is tightly coupled to implementation concerns (ie `AnnouncementService`) that could cause problems with testing the SUT in isolation. You should consider refactoring the code before addressing the problems with the current test.